# display all text in the textview with android when text is large

Tags: android, android-adapter

how to display all text in the textview with android when text is large ?
The full text is not displayed. 
my text for each row :

> "0x0: Installing devices with Id
>   PCI/VEN_8086&DEV_0116&SUBSYS_16421043&REV_09 using INF
>   C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/igdlh.inf_x86_neutral_50f5dc2f2dedc8cd/igdlh.inf"

output :

[image]

NewsAdapter clas :

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<News>  data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    public static Typeface phoneticFont;

    public NewsAdapter(Activity context, List<News> objects) {
        this.activity = context;
        this.data = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        phoneticFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/thoma.ttf");
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        private TextView titleTextView;
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView getTitleTextView() {
            titleTextView.setTypeface(phoneticFont);
            titleTextView.setTextSize(14);
            return titleTextView;
        }
        public void setTitleTextView(TextView titleTextView) {
            this.titleTextView = titleTextView;
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi=convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){

                /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows_news, null);

                /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.setTitleTextView((TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_news_TextView));
                holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image_news_ImageView);

               /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                vi.setTag( holder );
            }
            else 
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

            News news=data.get(position);

            holder.getTitleTextView().setText("0x0: Installing devices with Id PCI/VEN_8086&DEV_0116&SUBSYS_16421043&REV_09 using INF C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/igdlh.inf_x86_neutral_50f5dc2f2dedc8cd/igdlh.inf");
           // CommonMethods.setFont(activity, holder.text, 14);
            ImageView image = holder.image;

            //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(news.getImage(), image);

            /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
           // vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
            return vi;
        }
}
```

row_news.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_news_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loading"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/title_news_TextView"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_news_ImageView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news_ImageView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no help ?................

Answer (score 0):

In you TextView change
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
to
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
or some other defined width other than "wrap_content" which will force it to the width of the text it contains.